# Как тренировать FANN через PHP?

Tags: php, нейронные-сети, fann

Пытаюсь разобраться с работой нейросетей через PHP с помощью соответствующего расширения на примере старой [статьи на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/158729/), после которой само расширение для работы с FANN было переписано (как я понял) и начало работать по-другому. Вот я методом тыка создал сеть (потому что в документации ничего толком не описано):

```
$ann = fann_create_standard_array(3, array(256, 128, 3));
```

Дальше пытаюсь её учить. И тут возникает проблема: код, который указан в статье, также не работает. Более того, функция fann_train поменялась и теперь там в качестве третьего аргумента нужен массив с "desired outputs". Что это такое я не понимаю (да, я знаю как это переводится, но ясности перевод не добавляет). Вот как я пытался учить (опять же, методом тыка):

```
fann_train($ann, generate_frequencies(file_get_contents("en.txt")), array(1, 0, 0));
fann_train($ann, generate_frequencies(file_get_contents("ru.txt")), array(0, 1, 0));
fann_train($ann, generate_frequencies(file_get_contents("it.txt")), array(0, 0, 1));
```

Ошибок не выдаёт и "сеть" сохраняется в файл. Далее, при попытке протестировать сеть с разными языками выдаёт одинаковые вероятности. Т.е., вот код:

```
fann_run($ann, generate_frequencies("Привет, мы будем счастливы теперь и навсегда."));
fann_run($ann, generate_frequencies("Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musi"));
```

И везде выдаются одинаковые вероятности.

Что я делаю не так? Как заставить сеть работать?

P.S. Функция `generate_frequencies` из всё той же статьи. В каждом файле находится текст размером в 10000 символов на разных языках.

Comment: не надо мучать php, подергайте себе питон (серьезно).

Comment: @strangeqargo питоном я обязательно займусь, сейчас нет никакой возможности попробовать питон по некоторым причинам. Хочу попробовать разобраться хотя бы с php.

Answer (score -1):

Функция `fann_train` теперь работает по-другому. Она производит всего одну итерацию обучения. Вам нужно поместить блок с обучением в цикл, который повторится от 10000 раз.